Get all VMs with Monitoring Insights enabled
In the Azure portal, I can check/enable VM Monitoring Insights:

In the portal, we can get a list of VMs that are monitored here: https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring/AzureMonitoringBrowseBlade/~/virtualMachines
How can I, using the Python SDK (preferably) or the Azure CLI:

Get a list of all VMs in a subscription that do not have this feature enabled?
Enable Monitoring Insights?



Get a list of all VMs in a subscription that do not have this feature enabled?
Enable Monitoring Insights?

There are only below options to install VM Insights, refer the MS DOC for more details.

Here is a PowerShell script to enable VM Insights features on all VMs that are not already enabled in the subscription.
    Install-Script -Name Install-VMInsights
    
    $DcrResourceId =  "DCR_Resource-ID"
    $uamrgname = "User assigned managed identity rg name"
    $uamname ="User assigned managed identity name"
    $subid= "<SUB-ID>"
    $vmnames = Get-AzVM
    Foreach($vms in $vmnames){
    Write-Host : "Enabling VM Insight feature on VM name: $($vms.Name)"
    Install-VMInsights.ps1 -SubscriptionId $subid -ResourceGroup $vms.ResourceGroupName -Name $vms.Name -DcrResourceId $DcrResourceId -UserAssignedManagedIdentityName $uamrgname  -UserAssignedManagedIdentityResourceGroup $uamname
    }

Output:

After running the script, the VM Insights feature has been enabled on the VMs

Reference:   Enable VM insights by using PowerShell
Check VMInsights on VMs 

I haven't been able to find an API call that gives me what I need in an obvious (to me) fashion.
However, calling az vm extension list/ComputeManagementClient.virtual_machine_extensions and checking if the AzureMonitorLinuxAgent or AzureMonitorWindowsAgent exists seems to correlate with the information we get in the Portal about whether the Monitoring Insights is active in a specific VM.
